# Does $L\cdot S$ commute with $J^2$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, angular-momentum, commutator

I'm trying to calculate the commutator $[L\cdot S,J^2]$

The only way to proceed seems to write $L\cdot S=\frac{1}{2}(J^2-L^2-S^2)$

Now I'm left with $[L^2+S^2,J^2]$ and I'm stuck here. Any hint on how to proceed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would instead start by replacing $J^2$ with $L^2+S^2+2L\cdot S$. Then you'll be left with $[L\cdot S, L^2+S^2]$. Finally, write out $L\cdot S$ explicity as $L_xS_x+L_yS_y+L_zS_z$. From there, you can get the desired result using
$$[S_i,S^2]=[L_i,L^2]=0$$
(and of course $[S_i,L^2]$ and $[L_i,S^2]=0$ because the operators act on different spaces).

Comment: Sorry didn't see the notification and I did the same after following Griffith. Still thanks a lot.